# Accepting a pointer address?

Tags: c

*This is the source code*

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
int *p,a=5;
p=&a;
scanf("%d",p);
printf("%d\t",*p);
printf("%d",a);
}
```

How can we accept an address of a pointer?.Cuz it has the address of variable 'a' already.There are no errors shown by the compiler.
Also,i'm not able to understand the output.

output:(if my input is 45)

```
45   45
```

Comment: With `scanf("%d",p);` you are passing the address pointed by pointer `p`, which is the address of `a`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What do you mean by _accepting_ ?

Comment: Since `p=&a;`, `scanf("%d",p);` is the same as `scanf("%d",&a);`.

Comment: From `man scanf`: "*The  scanf()  family of functions scans input [...]; the results [...] are stored in the  locations **pointed to by the pointer arguments** that follow format.*"

Comment: Ahhhhhhh pointers, you've done it again.

Answer (score 1):

Your pointer is also a variable like `a` and has it's own address. You can access it by saying `&p`. But you say `scanf("%d", p);` so it is accessing pointer's pointing address.

EDIT: if you want to print pointer's address you can use `printf("%p\n",(void *) &p);`

Comment: but how can i accept the pointers pointing address?doesn't it have a fixed value?

Comment: when you define a pointer you allocate a memory space for that pointer. And you can't change it's address.

Comment: You need to cast to `(void *)` before printing the value of a pointer: `printf("%p\n", (void *) &p)`. Failure to do so is undefined behavior.

Comment: You can compile and run the code on some compilers i think. But it is safer so i will change my answer. Thank you.

Comment: You are right that it works sometimes (often?), but it is in the Standard, and I, for one, am not always lucky! ;)

Comment: That is a great link, @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc. Thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

You can access pointer itself by its address &p

```
int pa;
int *p;
scanf("%d", &pa);

p = (int*) pa;

printf("%p\t", p); // printing pointer stored address (got from input)
printf("%d\n", (void *) *p); // printing value stored in address stored in p, of course would be segfault in case of invalid address
```

Also use it with caution, its unportable and may resulting undefined behavior. it may work on 32bit machines because of int and int* have same length of bits but for other CPU's may not work.

Comment: What's the idea behind doing `scanf("%d", &p);`? In fact it provokes undefined behaviour, because `d` is defined to scan `int`s only.

Comment: I agree that its not portable, but in fact on 32 bit machine int and int* have same length, so we can copy contents of int to int*. The int could store the address of something but could not dereference it.

Comment: Cast to `(void *)` before printing an address. This is required by the Standard.